# How frequent is « pas souvent »?

Tags: sens

> Je crains de ne **pas** avoir **souvent** quitté mon pays.

I wonder if it is close to « de temps en temps {occasionally} » or more like « très rarement {very rarely} »?

Comment: I would say just *rarely*. *Très rarement* is an insistant form, which would be closer to *Je crains de ne vraiment pas avoir souvent quitté mon pays*.

Comment: It quite matches "not that much".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that it is closer to "très rarement", because of the presence of "Je crains de". For example "Je n'ai pas souvent quitté mon pays" would be close to "de temps en temps".

In both cases it depends on the context, especially on the person saying that in regard of his language habits.